# Почему не срабатывает switch?

Tags: html, select, javascript

```
$('#mySelectId').change(function () {
    num=this.options.selectedIndex;
    console.log(num);
});
   switch(num){
case "0":
    document.getElementById('justclick').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('getresponse').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('mailchimp').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('unisender').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('smartresponder').style.display = 'none';
break;
case "1":
    console.log("case=1");
    document.getElementById('justclick').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('getresponse').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('mailchimp').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('unisender').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('smartresponder').style.display = 'none';
break;
case "2":
    document.getElementById('justclick').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('getresponse').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('mailchimp').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('unisender').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('smartresponder').style.display = 'none';
break;
case "3":
    document.getElementById('justclick').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('getresponse').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('mailchimp').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('unisender').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('smartresponder').style.display = 'none';
break;
case "4":
    document.getElementById('justclick').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('getresponse').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('mailchimp').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('unisender').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('smartresponder').style.display = 'none';
break;
}
```

Comment: Не там разместили

    $('#mySelectId').change(function () {
        num=this.options.selectedIndex;
        // вот тут должен быть ваш switch
    });

P.S. Зачем вы используете jQuery, если у вас всё равно 90% на чистом JS?

Comment: @Deonis потому-что @Анатолийй не слушает вообще ничего что ему говорят. толку таким помогать - 0

Comment: @Deonis,@eicto
свитч там тоже не работает

http://jsfiddle.net/qtkqrsck/4/

Comment: Вы, по-моему, слишком толстый тролль. Не представляю, как человек в здравом уме может написать такое, уж простите. Для начала научитесь закрывать скобки. Потом почитайте про 'selected'. После этого осознайте разницу между строкой и числом.

Comment: И вообще заканчивайте этот спагетти-код и делайте отдельные функции!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

нет смысла здесь использовать этот гигантский свитч

```
jQuery(function($) {
var outMap=["#justclick",
            "#getresponse",
            "#mailchimp",
            "#mailchimp", //в оригинале куча одинаковых
            "#mailchimp,#smartresponder"]; //для демонстрации как два сразу выбрать
var outs=$(outMap.join(','));

$('#mySelectId').change(function () {
    var num=this.options.selectedIndex;
    console.log(num);
    outs.hide();
    $(outMap[num]).show();
}).change();

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/qx7qnsda/

Comment: премного благодарен